# Not able to send broadcast to another mobile in android app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

My Android.manifest has below declaration:-
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>`

I have a broadcast receiver defined in a service as below:-

```
package com.example.work;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import com.example.smallpayedwork.R;
import com.example.worker.DatabaseHelper;

import java.util.Random;

import static com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.internal.util.ThreadUtils.runOnUiThread;

public class WorkService extends Service {
    private static BroadcastReceiver workReceiver;
    private static Context mycontext;
    public WorkService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
     registerMyReceiver();
     IntentFilter filter= new IntentFilter("com.example.smallpayedwork.WORKER");
     filter.setPriority(999);
     this.registerReceiver(workReceiver,filter, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,null);
        runOnUiThread(() ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "Registered new service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        );
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        runOnUiThread(() ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "DeRegistering service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        );
        this.unregisterReceiver(workReceiver);
        workReceiver=null;
    }
    private void registerMyReceiver(){

        workReceiver= new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void  workreceiver(){};
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                runOnUiThread(() ->
                        Toast.makeText(context, "work details received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                );
                mycontext = context;
                Worknew wn = intent.getParcelableExtra("work");
                try {
                    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                    String areacode = db.getArea();
                    if (!areacode.equals("") && wn.getAreaCode().equals(areacode)) {
                        String status = wn.getStatus();
                        if (status.equals("Open")) db.addWork(wn);
                        else {
                            String userid = wn.getUserId();
                            String work = wn.getWork();
                            int cost = wn.getCost();
                            db.updateWork(userid, work, cost, status);
                        }
                        final PendingResult pendingResult = goAsync();
                        Task asyncTask = new Task(pendingResult, intent);
                        asyncTask.execute("");
                    }
                } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                    Log.e("WorkReceiver", "Local datastore is deleted");
                }

            }

            class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
                private final PendingResult pendingResult;
                private final Intent intent;


                private Task(PendingResult pendingResult, Intent intent) {
                    this.pendingResult = pendingResult;
                    this.intent = intent;
                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... s) {
                    Worknew wn1 = intent.getParcelableExtra("work");
                    String CHANNEL_ID = "1234";
                    NotificationChannel channel = null;
                    NotificationManager notificationManager;
                    notificationManager = mycontext.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        CharSequence name = mycontext.getString(R.string.channel_name);
                        String description = mycontext.getString(R.string.channel_description);
                        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
                        channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
                        channel.setDescription(description);
                        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                    }
                    Random random = new Random();
                    int x = random.nextInt(1000);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mycontext, DisplayWork.class);
                    String status = wn1.getStatus();
                    intent.putExtra("name", wn1.getName());
                    intent.putExtra("gender", wn1.getGender());
                    intent.putExtra("age", wn1.getAgeGroup());
                    intent.putExtra("work", wn1.getWork());
                    intent.putExtra("cost", "" + wn1.getCost());
                    intent.putExtra("userid", wn1.getUserId());
                    intent.putExtra("status", status);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mycontext, x, intent, 0);
                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
                    if (status.equals("Open")) {
                        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mycontext, CHANNEL_ID)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.work_img_background)
                                .setContentTitle("New Work created")
                                .setContentText("A new work has been created in your area code.")
                                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                .setAutoCancel(true);
                    } else {
                        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mycontext, CHANNEL_ID)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.work_img_background)
                                .setContentTitle("Status of work changed")
                                .setContentText("Status of work has changed in your area code.")
                                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                .setAutoCancel(true);
                    }
                    NotificationManagerCompat mnotificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(mycontext);

                    mnotificationManager.notify(x, builder.build());
                    return ("");
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                    super.onPostExecute(s);
                    pendingResult.finish();
                }
            }

        };

    }
}
```

I am registering service with the below command:-

`Intent intent1=new Intent(this, WorkService.class); startService(intent1);`  
And deregistering the service using below command:-

`Intent intent=new Intent(this, WorkService.class); stopService(intent);`

I am sending the below data to receiver:-

```
 Intent intent =new Intent("com.example.smallpayedwork.WORKER");
 intent.putExtra("work", wn);
 sendBroadcast(intent, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
```

It works fine when I create different accounts in 1 mobile and send the data but I am not receiving data when I send it from other connected device.

Comment: Broadcasts are within a single device. Broadcasts are not between devices. Broadcasts are not sent via text messages (so `SEND_SMS` is unrelated).

Comment: So how can we send notification to some other device in android?

Comment: So that means server is required in between to communicate between applications and there is no method of direct communication